# For which $a$ does this integral converge

Tags: calculus, integration, improper-integrals

So I have this integral: 
$$\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{x^a(x+a)^a}\,dx.$$ 
So I know that
$$\int_{a}^{\infty} \frac{1}{x^a}\,dx$$
converges for $a>1$.

But I need to find all real $a$ for which this integral will converge.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: The first integrand is asymptotic to $1/x^{2a}$. You can expect convergence for $a>1/2$.

Comment: @YvesDaoust. What happens around $x=0$ ?

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici: boum ! Indeed, around $0$ the integrand  is asymptotic to $1/x^a$, then divergence. The OP should check the lower bound.

Answer (score 1):

Hint. Let $a>0$. 
The integral over $[1,+\infty)$ is convergent iff $2a>1$ because as $x\to +\infty$
$$\frac{1}{x^a(x+a)^a}\sim\frac{1}{x^{2a}}.$$
On the other hand the integral over $[0,1]$ is convergent iff $a<1$ because as $x\to 0^+$
$$\frac{1}{x^a(x+a)^a}\sim\frac{1}{x^{a}a^a}.$$
What happens when $a\leq 0$?